# How can I invoke a custom model binder in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So it seems like several people (like [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jdothoffman/archive/2012/03/06/mvc-4-beta-web-api-bug-with-binding-route-values.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/27/disabling-model-binding-on-asp-net-web-apis-beta.aspx)) have had issues with **MVC4 model binding for ApiControllers**, but none of them seem to quite address the issue I'm seeing.

All I'd really like to do is change the array binding behavior for lists of integers.  So say I had a request type like this:

```
public class MyRequestModel
{
    public List<long> ListOfIntegers { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And an API GET method like this:

```
public ResultsResponseModel Get(MyRequestModel request)
{
    // use request.ListOfIntegers meaningfully

    ...

    return response;
}
```

I basically want to be able to say `/api/results/?listOfIntegers=1+2+3+4+5` and have that resolve to the `List<long>` property.

I've tried my usual model binding tricks, but as with most of the Web API in **MVC4 it appears to have a totally separate path for model binding.**

The furthest I've gotten is using a `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder` attribute on `MyRequestModel`, and creating a model binder that "implemented" `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder`.  That consistently yields an object reference exception with stack traces that never touch my code.

Anyone hit this?  Have thoughts on what to try next?

**UPDATE**:  Here's a stack trace that I've captured in my custom `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.DefaultActionValueBinder.BindParameterValue(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpParameterBinding parameterBinding)
    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.DefaultActionValueBinder.<>c__DisplayClass1.BindValuesAsync>b__0(RequestContentReadKind contentReadKind)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass38.<ToAsyncVoidTask>b__37()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: can you submit the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking ApiControllers, then you're trying to model bind in Web API and now MVC
Here's a sample model binder

```
  public class MyRequestModelBinderProvider : ModelBinderProvider
    {
        MyRequestModelBinder binder = new MyRequestModelBinder();
        public IdeaModelBinderProvider()
        {          
        }

        public override IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(MyRequestModel))
            {
                return binder;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of registering a custom model binder provider

```
 IEnumerable<object> modelBinderProviderServices = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.GetServices(typeof(ModelBinderProvider));
 List<Object> services = new List<object>(modelBinderProviderServices);
 services.Add(new MyRequestModelBinderProvider());
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetServices(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), services.ToArray());
```

Now in your custom model binder you use the contexts to access the querystring values

```
  public class MyRequestModelBinder :  IModelBinder
    {
        public MyRequestModelBinder()
        {

        }

        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            MyRequestModel yourModel; 
            //use contexts to access query string values
            //create / update your model properties

            bindingContext.Model = yourModel;  
            //return true || false if binding is successful
        }
```

Make sure your using the classes and interfaces for WebAPI and not MVC. Some of the names are the same, but different namespaces and dlls

Comment: OK so I think I've got the right structure in place.  Do you know if there's any way to invoke default Web API model binding and then just manually take control of the list value parameters within the model binder?

Comment: call base.GetBinder in your custom ModelBinderProvide to get the default model binder, and put it into a private filed of your custom model binder, so you can use it from your model binder.

Comment: @FrancescoAbbruzzese I'd love to do something like that - unfortunately, since we're inheriting from ModelBinderProvider, which is an abstract class with an abstract base GetBinder method, there's not a default one ready to go for me.  I've tried sending instantiations from types in `System.Web.Http.Modelbinding.ModelBinders` without much luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: mmm the point is that the default model binder is not public, and since we cannot get a copy of the default model binder...it is hard to find a way out. It seems that there is a design choice "to hide" completely the functionalities of the default model binder. A possible dirty trick is: use the sources, that now are available, to define a PUBLIC default model binder...Needless to say I don't like this:) In the next days I will start studying the sources...so maybe  I will find some other extension point...but I get the feel that the default model binder has been made completely hidden

Comment: +1 and accepted - I'd still like to be able to invoke default model binding first within a custom binder, that should probably become a separate question.  This gave me the extension point I was looking for to take control of model binding for a specific type.  @FrancescoAbbruzzese I'll probably have another question out on this soon if you find any other hooks :)

Comment: You should be able to call GetServices on the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver object to get the default. Then maybe you can wrap it with your custom and invoke when required... this is just a guess though

Comment: @BrandonLinton maybe I don't understood you correctly but if you return the null in you custom provider the system will fall back to the default automatically. Check this blog post http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt9-model-binders.html

Comment: @Calin yeah that post is specific to MVC3 although it does look like the same idea w/ ModelBinderProviders.  The catch here is that I still want my custom model binder returned by the provider - I just want, within that provider, to basically 'run' default model binding first, then lay my own custom list-binding logic over top of it.

Comment: @BrandonLinton the mvc code is on codeplex go grab that binder code and put in your project, the class is not public :)

Comment: Any update on this? It doesn't appear to work for MVC 4 RC as the DependencyResolver is different.

Comment: Seems like they're still make changes to the public API. I'd wait for RTM to see what ends up in it

Comment: Why does the `BindModel()` function return bool? If I could successfully extracted the content I want and deserialize it into an object, how am I supposed to pass the object to the next phase?

Comment: If successful then you set the created model on the binding context. I've updated the post