# How can I invoke default model binding within a custom binder in MVC4 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I recently posed a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096957/how-can-i-invoke-a-custom-model-binder-in-mvc4) on Stack Overflow about finding the right extensibility point for model binding in the Web API beta.  Using a custom provider / `IModelBinder` gives me full control of model binding and access to the value providers.

However, it's really too much control.  I just want to control how a couple of values are mapped, and don't want to hand-code model binding that would've otherwise worked just fine.

Ultimately, this is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Invoke default model binding

        // Pull out custom values
        var value1 = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("value1");
        var value2 = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("value2");

        bindingContext.Model.Value1 = DoCustomStuff(value1);
        bindingContext.Model.Value2 = DoCustomStuff(value2);

        return true;
    }

    ... // Define DoCustomStuff
}
```

It looks like it's pretty hard to get ahold of a default provider for the WebAPI.  **Does anyone know if it's accessible and how it should be accessed here in a custom model binder?**

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure in Web API but in MVC you can inherit from DefaultModelBinder and call base.BindModel

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the Web API is a totally different animal right now in the beta.  The default binder provider operation is an abstract method.

Comment: This has a tag of `asp.net-web-api` which has very different model binding than `MVC`, so this answer is not helpful at all.